# Ids and List<Account> after insert

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, dml, insert, method

In an Apex class method, I want to add several Accounts to a List. After a successful execution of the insert, can I access Ids?

Example:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
Account newAccount = new Account();
newAccount.Name = 'Acme, Inc.';
accounts.Add(newAccount);
insert accounts;

for (Account thisAccount: accounts) {
  System.debug(thisAccount.Id);
}
```

Will thisAccount.Id have a value or must I execute a new SOQL statement?

Per [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm) under **Inserting Related Records**, it looks like it should contain the newly-assigned Salesforce Id.

Comment: As a first step running the code in anonymous would have given you the answer. May save you some time next time waiting for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every `insert` DML operation that you successfully perform populates the `Id` field of the inserted sObject.